# Equivalent to null alt text for purely decorative videos

Tags: html, html5-video, accessibility, alt, wcag2.0

Our marketing department has made a new homepage for our site that uses a looped .mp4 file of people walking down a hallway that's being used as the background for our header/logo area.  It has absolutely no relevance to the content and should be ignored by screen readers.  Is there a way to mark a video (using the `<video>` tag) as purely decorative, similar to how you would use `<img alt="">`?

In terms of WCAG 2.0 compliance for the site, there is no sound to the video so captions/audio description are also inappropriate.  Ideally I'm looking for a solution that can be used to claim Level A and AA compliance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having no `track` element should be sufficient, but it's better to set the `aria-hidden=true` attribute on the `video` element in order to make sure that the screenreader won't announce the element.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that, that makes perfect sense.  Thank you!